# Singular or plural: "What I have read recently is textbooks/a textbook"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

1. What I have read recently is a textbook.
2. What I have read recently is textbooks.

Are both acceptable? Are there better ways to describe these situations?

Comment: This question is a request for proofreading, which is [off-topic on this site](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Before someone closes this question, please [edit] it and include what aspect of learning English you're uncertain about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have read a single textbook then your first sentence is correct:

> What I have read recently is a textbook.

If you have read multiple textbooks then you'd use your second sentence, although with a small correction:

> What I have read recently *are* textbooks.

However, these both sound a bit awkward. You'd be more likely to hear a native speaker say

> I have recently read a textbook.
>
> I have recently read some textbooks.